# Googles AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize() method freezing on canceled auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, blocking, playn, google-oauth-java-client

I have a Java application that needs to get users to authorize my application's access to Google services. I have the following bit of code in place to show and obtain the authorization I need:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JsonFactory, clientSecrets, scopes).build();
Credential cred = null; 
try
  {
    LocalServerReceiver localSrv = new LocalServerReceiver();

    AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp app = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localSrv);

    cred = app.authorize(userName);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
    refreshToken = cred.getRefreshToken();
```

If the user clicks on the 'Authorize' or 'Cancel' buttons everything's fine. If they close the browser window however, the entire application freezes. Is there a way to handle this case to prevent the freezing or introduce a timeout?

Comment: What does 'freezing' mean? No response?

Comment: The process hangs and the entire application becomes non-responsive. Even eclipse can't kill it at that point, but the process has to be terminated manually.

Comment: If it's the same thing I'm seeing, the call to app.authorize() does a Thread.wait() until the auth code is redirected back from the login page. If the login page is closed, then that auth code never gets sent back, then the application will appear frozen, but really it's waiting. Unfortunately I don't yet know what the solution for this is.

Comment: @ChargerIIC Hey I did the same to get Authorized for Google Service. But I'm initiating from JAVA Backend and authorization URL is there in console. So I've to cOPY PASTE it to browser to grant access. Is there any way that It'll open automatically in Browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're also integrating Google Drive into our application, and this is a concern of mine. What happens is that if you call the `authorize()` method, whatever thread the call is on will block. You'll notice that while the authorization window is open, the application also isn't responsive.

I was hoping that there would be a way to detect if the user closed the authorization window, but it seems like this will only cause the `LocalServerReceiver` to wait endlessly for a token that will never arrive.

Your best bet at this point is to **call `authorize()` asynchronously**, and to wait for a response.

Edit: I took a peek at the `LocalServerReceiver` source code because we wanted the receiver to redirect to a different URL rather than display plain text. It implements the `VerificationCodeReceiver` interface, which has a blocking `waitForCode()` method. It seems like it's necessary for `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize()` to block while waiting, even if you make your own implementation of `VerificationCodeReceiver`.

Comment: Now that I've got more programmer experience under my belt I'm forced to agree. It's really unfortunate that it isn't non-blocking.

Comment: @ChargerIIC Have you or Aaron ran into issues where the localserverreceiver isn't able to get the response, even after logging in with google and it stating that it's been authorized?

Comment: @CamHart Hey, sorry, but I've been reassigned to different projects since 2017, so I haven't touched the code base since. In my experience, this has happened intermittently when logging in with 2FA using phone notifications, but it seems to have gone away. I think it might be an issue on Google's end. Sorry I can't help more