# Cancel google OAuth2 authorization

Tags: google-oauth, jetty, interrupt, google-api-java-client

I am creating a java desktop app that needs access to Google APIs.

I authorize the application like this:

```java
Details credentialDetails=...;
List<String> scopes=...;
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets=new GoogleClientSecrets();
clientSecrets.setInstalled(credentialDetails);
LocalServerReceiver receiver=new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
NetHttpTransport httpTransport=GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), clientSecrets, scopes)
    .setAccessType("offline").build();
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver)
    .authorize("user");
```

`authorize()` then waits until the authorization finishes using `LocalServerReceiver#waitForCode` that uses `Condition#awaitUninterruptibly`.

The problem is that the user could e.g. close the browser window and ignore the authorization and I need to cancel it (from another thread).

I tried using `receiver.stop();` but while `stop()` is executed, the `Condition` is not `signal()`ed and the thread doing the authorization stays stuck in `Condition#awaitUninterruptibly`.

Normal interruption also doesn't work as the `LocalServerReceiver#waitForCode` uses `Condition#awaitUninterruptibly`.

**How can I cancel the OAuth2 authorization from another thread?**

I am using `com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0`.

Comment: Past answer that doesn't address how to cancel, but explains why it behaves like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38475819/775715

Comment: I am already calling `authorize` asynchronously but the user might never authorize the application.

Comment: Perhaps upgrade?  The newest versions of `google-oauth-client-jetty` (version 1.31.5) uses a `Semaphore` (instead of a `Condition`) which is specifically released on `LocalServerReceiver.stop()` now.

Comment: I originally tried using that but it caused other problems. But I'll try again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With version 1.22.0 you cannot use `LocalServerReceiver#stop()` to cancel the pending `authorize()`.

This is a bug, and was opened as an issue at https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/issues/127

Which was addressed in version 1.23.0